# Ember Octane when calling a save on the model what is the default accept and content-type headers?

Tags: json, ember.js, asp.net-core-3.1

In Ember Octane, when calling a save on the model, which calls a save to the back-end (.NET CORE 3.1), what is the default `accept` and `content-type` headers? I have tried looking online, but I cannot seem to find anything in the documentation.

Is it `application/json` or `application/vnd.api+json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the adapter you are using , the default one is json-api , 
the latest JSON API specification says

> Clients MUST send all JSON:API data in request documents with the
>   header Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json without any media type
>   parameters

[REF](https://jsonapi.org/format/)