# ASP.NET Core 3.1 How can I get the controller to use System.Text.Json to serialize and deserialize

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1

I am converting from .NET CORE 2.2 to 3.1. Is it possible to force the controller to use `System.Text.Json` to serialize and deserialize any incoming request and response? Basically, when the request comes in I want to use `System.Text.Json` and when a response goes out I want to use `System.Text.Json`. If yes, how?

The reason for doing this is that Microsoft is really pushing this library as the replacement for `Newtonsoft.Json` as being so much safer and faster. But, I cannot seem to find any documentation on Microsoft's pages that reflects this. I find it hard that Microsoft would not update their code to utilize this new library.

**UPDATE**

I am unable to get `System.Text.Json` to bind the model by parsing with `application/vnd.api+json` - the model is NULL. It will only bind if I parse using `application/json`. This is problematic because the JSON:API specification requires `application/vnd.api+json` (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61452011/4630376). I tried decorating the controller with `[Consumes("application/vnd.api+json")]`, but that does not work.

How do I get `System.Text.Json` to bind models using `application/vnd.api+json`? My initial assumption in asking this question is that .NET Core 3.1 was not using `System.Text.Json`. Since no one has provided an answer, other than a few comments, I have opted to expand this question.

**ChangePassword Model:**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace ABC.Model.Clients
{
    public class ChangePassword
    {   
        public ChangePassword() { }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("old-password")]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("new-password")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("confirm-password")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Postman request:**

```
{ 
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
            "old-password" : "**********",
            "new-password" : "**********",
            "confirm-password" : "**********"
        },
        "type": "change-passwords"
    }
}
```

Comment: James Newton-King the author of NewtonSoft.Json works at Microsoft these days. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/ even Scott Hanselman covers it https://www.hanselman.com/blog/UpdatingMyASPNETPodcastSiteToSystemTextJsonFromNewtonsoftJson.aspx

Comment: How do you know the requests are not using `System.Text.Json`?

Comment: nots not any safer.... faster? it lacks like 100 of the features... so when they are apples to apples sure but as its stands they do not have same feature sets...

Comment: A 3.0+ project will use `System.Text.Json` unless you tell it to use `Newtonsoft.Json` with  `.AddNewtonsoftJson()` in `Startup.ConfigureServices()`.

Comment: Do your models use public properties or public fields? When I migrated from 2.2 to 3.1 all my models were blank until I refactored them with public properties instead of public fields.

Comment: @jason smith Do you mean using the `JsonPropertyName` decorator? If yes, then yes I am using that.

Comment: No, I'm not refering to that. I had models that used public fields like this: `public string Name;` I had to change them to properties: `public string Name {get; set;}` in order for `System.Text.Json` to bind to them properly. I think there may be a configuration setting to bind to fields instead of props, but in my case it was easy to update the few models that I had.

Comment: @JasonSmith Got it. Yes, I already had that set. I have updated my question to provide a model that I have migrated.

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: Have you added `application/vnd.api+json` to supported media types?

Comment: It think, there is also no need to create almost the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61483906/net-core-3-1-unable-to-parse-content-type-application-vnd-apijson)

Comment: @pavelanikhouski How do I check/set the supported media type? Is it in the  `startup.cs` file? If you are asking if I have it is in the Postman post request, then yes that is already set.

Comment: @JWeezy You can try to add this media type to `SupportedMediaTypes` of [`InputFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.inputformatter?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Can you post an answer with some detail please?

Comment: See the first part of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59813295/2630078).

Comment: @KirkLarkin That did not work. When I debug, I see that there are already three entries: `application/json`, `text/json`, and `application/*+json`. The last one seems to indicate that `application/vnd.api+json` is supported via the asterisk wild card - if I am reading that correctly.

Comment: Oh yeah, it's not about the media-type at all. It's about the fact your incoming JSON is a different structure to the `ChangePassword` model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Core 3.0 by default uses System.Text.Json. Check also the [official documentation article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-3.0?view=aspnetcore-3.1#new-json-serialization) where this is described.

Regarding the `application/vnd.api+json` and the [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/) support in .NET Core 3.0. I am not aware of any support for this in ASP.NET Core. This is a separate standard from plain web API. You cannot just add it as another type you accept and expect it to work.

I found a project on GitHub [JSON API .Net Core](https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore) that provides a framework for building [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/) compliant web API services. The version for .NET Core 3.0 is at the moment still in Alpha and currently uses Newtonsoft.Json which is not what you want. You can look at the source to see how to handle such requests and maybe build your own solution based on it. Or join the project and help them to make also a `System.Text.Json` version.

Comment: I think I found some support for what you say from Microsoft's site, where it says `By default, ASP.NET Core supports application/json, text/json, and text/plain media types.` What is odd is that `test/plain` is no longer listed as an imputFormatter - it is replaced by `application/vnd.api+json`. Is it possible to build a custom formatter to achieve this?

Comment: I don't see any mention of that in the latest documentation. They talk only about `application/json` and `application/xml` format support out of the box. Check [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#define-supported-request-content-types-with-the-consumes-attribute). The plain text support is provided as a sample for a [custom input formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-3.1). The `TextInputFormatter` is a base class for all formatters that accept text input.

Comment: Do you have any context on why `application/vnd.api+json` is not supported in ASP.NET Core? It seems wild that it is not supported in the age on front-end frameworks that seem to require it.

Comment: I think because this is a third party standard that is not very widely adopted (maybe I'm wrong about that but I have not heard much about it). I also has already many open source implementations. If you want more details you can ask the Microsoft ASP.NET Core team or open a feature request that they add it maybe if many people like it they will do it. Check also the [implementations page on the JSON:API site](https://jsonapi.org/implementations/#server-libraries-net) and you will see there are also some other implementations for C#. For .NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `application/vnd.api+json` media type for the `SupportedMediaTypes` of `SystemTextJsonInputFormatter`.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    var formatter = options.InputFormatters.OfType<SystemTextJsonInputFormatter>().FirstOrDefault();
    formatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/vnd.api+json");
});
```